# I want to extract a number from a file then perform simple mathematics operation then paste it to another file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, extract, copy-and-paste

Hello everybody please help me to write a script to do the below please:

1. I want to open a text file named C60_GRM_box.gro (I copied the first lines from this file below) and then extract the second line which is 127240 below;

> ```
> GRM in vacuum
> 127240
>     1GRM     C1    1   0.061   0.071   0.000
>     1GRM     C2    2   0.184   0.142   0.000
> ```

2. Then, I want to subtract 2800 from the number extracted in step one and then divide the result by 60

what I want to do: (the number extracted in step number 1 - 2800)/60 = result

3. Finally I want to open another txt file named C60_GRM_box.top (I have copied below all the data in the text file I want to replace part of it) and replace a number (which is the number beside the word G8LE, which is 3000 below)  with the result I obtained in step 2, I have pasted all the content of the second file named C60_GRM_box.top below;

> ```
> ; Include forcefield parameters
> include "/home/abdelaal/Desktop/GROMACS/C60:TAPC/C60_GRM/41/gromos54a7.ff/forcefield.itp"
>
> ; Include topology for GRM
> include "/home/abdelaal/Desktop/GROMACS/C60:TAPC/C60_GRM/41/GRM.itp"
> ifdef POSRES
> include "/home/abdelaal/Desktop/GROMACS/C60:TAPC/C60_GRM/41/posrestr.itp"
> endif
>
> ; Include topology for C60
> include "/home/abdelaal/Desktop/GROMACS/C60:TAPC/C60_GRM/41/C60.itp"
>
> [ system ]
>
> ; Name
>
> GRM in vacuum 
>
> [ molecules ]
>
> ; Compound                 #mols
>
> GRM                           1
>
> G8LE                     strong text    3000
> ```

I don't need to open the files in steps 1 and 3, if I can do all the above without opening the files that would be perfect.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this bash shell script does what you want, but you can tweak it to change the source/target features.

assuming `source.txt` contains the source data; `target.txt` is the one that you want to replace

```
# get the 2nd line or source.txt-2800
val=$(expr `head -2 source.txt | tail -1` - 2800)
export val2=$(expr $val / 60)
# replace the result
perl -pi -e 's/(G8LE\s+[^\d]*)\d+/$1$ENV{val2}/g' target.txt
```

Comment: I created a text file named trial2.txt and pasted inside it the below:      
                                                                                                                                   #!/bin/bash 

val=$(expr `head -2 C60_GRM_box.gro | tail -1` - 2800)
export val2=$(expr $val / 60)
perl -pi -e 's/(G8LE\s+[^\d]*)\d+/$1$ENV{val2}/g' C60_GRM_box.top

and then I opened a terminal and I wrote: bash trial2.txt

but nothing happened, what is wrong please in what I have done ?

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :) 
Many thankssssssss for your effort:)